# Do I need to set up a HomeGroup, a Workgroup or Domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, workgroup, windows-networking

I have 6 PCs. All 6 PCs have Windows 7 Ultimate OS Installed. I want to create a Network and have control on all systems.

It should be 1+5. i.e. One should be the Main system. The rest of the 5 PCs should be connected to the Main PC. The 5 connected PCs should have access to the Main System for Network Printing and Network Scanning. All the 5 PCs should not have any other access to the Main System.

The Main System should have all access and full control over all other 5 PCs. It should have access to Delete, Modify, Write, Read, etc.

All the 5 PCs are directly connected to the switch port with each seperate network cable(ie. a cable from each system connected to the switch port. (totally 5 cables). The switch is directly connected to the Modem.

The Main System is also connected to the switch port with a seperate cable.

The 5 PCs can or cannot be accessible from each other – no issues whatever it is.

So now the main task is: How to configure the sytem network for this setup? Whether it should be a Home Group or Workgroup or Domain?

Help me with a schematic diagram if possible.

Comment: This is like saying "I need to chop up an onion. Should I use a fork, a spoon or a knife? I don't have any forks or knives." - Without Windows Server there's not a lot you can do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want central management of client machines, you need Active Directory. You can't do this without a Windows Server OS, though. There's no good way to get what you want with only client operating systems.

Comment: arguably you can always install virtual box/vmware player, underneath linux with samba and try setting up pdc but.. i dont think that's what the author is after.

Comment: @pQd, you've read the question. Do you really think this person is capable of installing and configuring a Samba system?

Comment: @pQd Even so, a Samba PDC will only give you central auth, no group policy.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers that's why i'm saying that most probably it's not what the author is looking for.